# Smooth path in javaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm drawing a `Path` in JavaFX and I would like to draw path (`lineTo` and `arcTo`) of this type:
[image: picture only for illustration]

Is there any simple way how to connect arcs with lines(and other arcs) to get a smooth path like this?

I don't know the perimeter of an arc, I know only the beginning point and ending point. In the picture are only half circles, I need to draw another types of `arcTo` as well.

The only idea, I've had so far was getting the direction of the end of the path and then counting and joining another `arcTo` / `lineTo` in this direction. However, I didn't found any method to do this as well.

Comment: For a given length, how often should the arcs be? Also, please clarify on these "other types of `arcTo`"

Comment: I'm looking for general solution of connecting arcs smoothly to lines, not only for one case of this (the image was only for illustration of the problem), therefore I can't specify, how often should the arcs be. Under other type of arcTo I mean arcs with central angle different  from 180°

Comment: So you have a given array/list of arcs that you want to connect?

Comment: No, I always have a line and a point somewhere in the `Pane`. I want to draw an `arcTo` beginning at a specified end of the line and ending in the given point.

Answer (score 5):

A [Cubic Bezier Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) is defined by four points, `start`, `end`, and two "control points" `control1` and `control2`. It has the property that

- it starts and ends at `start` and `end`
- initially (i.e. at `start`) it is tangential to the line segment between `start` and `control1`
- at `end` it is tangential to the line segment between `control2` and `end`

The shape of the curve is also determined by the sizes of the line segments from `start` to `control1` and `control2` to `end`: roughly speaking these control the "speed" with which the line approaches the control points before turning towards the end points.

So to join two line segments with a smooth curve, you can use a cubic curve whose start is the end of the first line segment and whose end is the start of the second line segment. Compute the control points just by extending each line beyond its end (first line) or start (second line). Using the same length for the extensions will give a balanced look.

Here is an example. Run this code: drag the mouse across the pane to draw one line, then again to draw a second line, and the two lines will be connected by a cubic curve.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurve;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JoinLineSegmentsWithCubic extends Application {

    private Line unconnectedLine = null ;
    private Line currentDraggingLine = null ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setOnDragDetected(e -> {
            currentDraggingLine = new Line(e.getX(), e.getY(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            pane.getChildren().add(currentDraggingLine);
        });
        pane.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            if (currentDraggingLine != null) {
                currentDraggingLine.setEndX(e.getX());
                currentDraggingLine.setEndY(e.getY());
            }
        });
        pane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
            if (currentDraggingLine != null) {
                currentDraggingLine.setEndX(e.getX());
                currentDraggingLine.setEndY(e.getY());

                if (unconnectedLine != null) {
                    connect(unconnectedLine, currentDraggingLine, pane);
                }
                unconnectedLine = currentDraggingLine ;
                currentDraggingLine = null ;
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void connect(Line line1, Line line2, Pane parent) {
        Point2D line1Start = new Point2D(line1.getStartX(), line1.getStartY());
        Point2D line1End = new Point2D(line1.getEndX(), line1.getEndY());
        Point2D line2Start = new Point2D(line2.getStartX(), line2.getStartY());
        Point2D line2End = new Point2D(line2.getEndX(), line2.getEndY());

        double line1Length = line1End.subtract(line1Start).magnitude();
        double line2Length = line2End.subtract(line2Start).magnitude();

        // average length:
        double aveLength = (line1Length + line2Length) / 2 ;

        // extend line1 in direction of line1 for aveLength:
        Point2D control1 = line1End.add(line1End.subtract(line1Start).normalize().multiply(aveLength));

        // extend line2 in (reverse) direction of line2 for aveLength:
        Point2D control2 = line2Start.add(line2Start.subtract(line2End).normalize().multiply(aveLength));

        CubicCurve cc = new CubicCurve(
                line1End.getX(), line1End.getY(), 
                control1.getX(), control1.getY(), 
                control2.getX(), control2.getY(), 
                line2Start.getX(), line2Start.getY());

        cc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        cc.setFill(null);

        parent.getChildren().add(cc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

You can also incorporate a cubic Bezier curve into a path, using the path element [`CubicCurveTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/CubicCurveTo.html). Here is an example using a Path, with vertical line segments connected by cubic bezier curves (the method generating the path will work for arbitrary line segments):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.LineTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SmoothPathWithCubicBezier extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        double[] points = new double[24];
        for (int i = 0; i < 24 ; i+=8) {
            double x = (1 + i/8) * 200 ;
            points[i] = x ;
            points[i+1] = 200 ;
            points[i+2] = x ;
            points[i+3] = 400 ;
            points[i+4] = x + 100 ;
            points[i+5] = 400 ;
            points[i+6] = x+ 100 ;
            points[i+7] = 200 ;
        }
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(createPath(points));

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 800, 800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    // points should be an array of length a multiple of four, 
    // defining a set of lines {startX1, startY1, endX1, endY1, startX2, ...}
    // The path will consist of the straight line segments, joined by
    // cubic beziers
    private Path createPath(double[] points) {
        Path path = new Path();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < points.length; i+=4) {
            double startX = points[i];
            double startY = points[i+1];
            double endX = points[i+2];
            double endY = points[i+3];

            if (i==0) {
                MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(startX, startY);
                moveTo.setAbsolute(true);
                path.getElements().add(moveTo);
            } else {

                double lastStartX = points[i-4];
                double lastStartY = points[i-3];
                double lastEndX = points[i-2];
                double lastEndY = points[i-1];

                double lastLength = Math.sqrt((lastEndX-lastStartX)*(lastEndX-lastStartX)
                        + (lastEndY-lastStartY)*(lastEndY-lastStartY));
                double length = Math.sqrt((endX-startX)*(endX-startX)
                        + (endY-startY)*(endY-startY));
                double aveLength = (lastLength+length)/2;

                double control1X = lastEndX + (lastEndX-lastStartX)*aveLength/lastLength ;
                double control1Y = lastEndY + (lastEndY-lastStartY)*aveLength/lastLength ;

                double control2X = startX - (endX-startX)*aveLength/length ;
                double control2Y = startY - (endY-startY)*aveLength/length ;

                CubicCurveTo cct = new CubicCurveTo(control1X, control1Y, control2X, control2Y, startX, startY);
                cct.setAbsolute(true);
                path.getElements().add(cct);

            }
            LineTo lineTo = new LineTo(endX, endY);
            lineTo.setAbsolute(true);
            path.getElements().add(lineTo);

        }

        return path ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This gives

[image]